# Carregar modal apenas uma vez

Tags: java, jsf, rich-faces

Tenho um modal que é carregado depois do login (automatico), porem a cada refresh o modal abre, eu preciso que ele abra somente uma vez depois de logar.

```
<rich:modalPanel id="modal" autosized="true" width="500" height="200" showWhenRendered="#{true}">
        <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:graphicImage value="/img/fechando.png" onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('modalMensagem')"
                id="botaoFechar" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText value="Olá" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{bean.mensagem}" escape="true" style="font-size:15px;"/>
    </rich:modalPanel>
```

tela2.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:form id="main">
        <rich:messages styleClass="msgerro" globalOnly="true" />

        <center style="font-size: 10pt;">
            Olá
            <br />
        </center>
    </h:form>

    <ui:include src="/modal/modalMensagem.xhtml"/>
</ui:define>
```

BEAN

```
public String getMensagem() {
    return MENSAGEM;
}
```

Preciso de um metodo que entre de fato no false, pra abrir somente uma vez? Ja que o showWhenRendered por padrao é true.

Comment: Se você quer abrir apenas uma vez após o primeiro login, vai ter que gravar no banco de dados uma flag dizendo que já abriu uma vez. Caso você deseje abrir a primeira vez por sessão, pode colocar essa flag como um atributo da sessão e utilizar ele como condicional para não abrir a popup.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo, pra eu verificar como faz? Algum tutorial...

Comment: Caso não queira gravar no banco de dados, você pode gravar no local storage do usuário.

Comment: Algum exemplo? Pois não sei se criar um metodo setando false resolveria...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu adotaria a seguinte abordagem:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="modal" autosized="true" width="500" height="200" showWhenRendered="#{homePageMB.showWelcomeModal()}">
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:graphicImage value="/img/fechando.png" onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('modalMensagem')"
            id="botaoFechar" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText value="Olá" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.mensagem}" escape="true" style="font-size:15px;"/>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

E em seu managed bean (o que eu dei o nome carinhosamente de `HomePageMB`), você teria uma checagem mais ou menos assim:

```
public class HomePageMB {
    ...

    private static final String CHECKED_WELCOME_MODAL = "checkedWelcomeModal";

    public boolean showWelcomeModal() {
        Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();

        if(sessionMap.get(CHECKED_WELCOME_MODAL) == null) {
            sessionMap.put(CHECKED_WELCOME_MODAL, true);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Com isso caso seja o primeiro login, a flag vai estar nula na sessão, e após ao voltar para a home page ele já vai ter a flag na sessão, e a modal não será aberta.

Como mencionei no comentário, existem outras soluções para este problema, depende da sua necessidade.

Comment: Bom demais sua ajuda, mas dessa forma, o modal não abre...

Comment: Eu não postei uma configuração completa do managed bean, você aplicou em um que está funcionando em seu projeto?

Comment: Sim, fiz no seu modelo implementando no meu.

Comment: Chegou a debugar pra ver se está retornando `true`? Se não está sendo realizado o evaluate depois da renderização da tela?